# How to get ips that a certain process is connecting to in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, networking, ip

So I am writing a C# program to manage a web server on Windows. I have it so the web server software starts with the users typed in configuration and starts the web server successfully. However, I am struggling with getting the IP addresses that the web server software is connecting to. I am attempting to show incoming and outgoing connection IPs of a certain exe but am only able to show all incoming outgoing connections of the whole computer not just one specific process exe like I am trying to. Here is the code where I am attempting to do this:

```
private void ipmonitor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            IPAddress[] addrList = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList;
            string IP = addrList[0].ToString();
            richTextBox2.Text = IP;
        }
    }
    }
```

Is there a way to do this in C# code? Thanks.

Comment: It depends if you are using DHCP for IP addresses or hard coding the addresses.  For DHCP you should always use the computer name instead of the IP address.  You can also ping the device to get the MAC which contains the manufacturer, model, and serial number to make sure you are getting data from the correct device.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run netstat, and parse the result. see [a great example here](https://www.cheynewallace.com/get-active-ports-and-associated-process-names-in-c/) for inspiration.

```
using (Process p = new Process()) 
{
    ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
    ps.Arguments = "-a -n -o";
    ps.FileName = "netstat.exe";
    ps.UseShellExecute = false;
    ps.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    ps.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    ps.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    ps.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo = ps;
    p.Start();
    StreamReader stdOutput = p.StandardOutput;
    StreamReader stdError = p.StandardError;
    string content = stdOutput.ReadToEnd() + stdError.ReadToEnd();
    string exitStatus = p.ExitCode.ToString();
    // inpect and parse content and exitStatus for errors
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: @user14527374, Is any update? If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.